# Find an object in a list based on attribute value in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a simple way to find an object in a list based on an attribute value, without looping on the list?

For example given a list like the following :

```
var lst = [
  {
    name: "foo", 
    value: "fooValue"
  }, 
  {
    name: "bar", 
    value: "barValue"
  }
];
```

Is there some kind of "`find`" method, such that `lst.find("name", "foo")` would return the object which has a "`name`" attribute with the value "`foo`"?

Comment: At most, the loop would be hidden from you, but still execute inside some other function. If that is acceptable you can use the `filterFilter` service.

Comment: I know a loop has to be done somehow, I'm just searching for a lighter syntax.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the $filter service:

```
angular.module('app', [])

function ParentCtrl($scope, $filter){
    var lst = [{name : "foo", value : "fooValue"}, {name: "bar", value: "barValue"}, { name: 'foo', value: 'something else'}];
    var newTemp = $filter("filter")(lst, {name:'foo'});
    console.log(newTemp);
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/W2Z86/

Comment: Thanks @matthew-berg . For other noobs (like me). In case it's not immediately obvious, newTemp is an array of objects that match the filter. If you know you've got a single object that matches, you might want the first element in the array (i.e. newTemp[0] ).

Answer (score 6):

If you want a strict comparison, you need to set the comparator (3rd argument) to true like the following (based on Mathew's answer):

```
var newTemp = $filter("filter")(lst, {name:'foo'}, true);
```

See the doc on $filter on AngularJS site: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter